# How can I retrieve all documents whose property is a substring of a given parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Mongoose Schema

```
var People= new Schema({
      firstName: String,
      alias: [String]
});
```

I am looking for a way to return all documents where one of the `alias` strings match *or exist as a substring* within a given value.

For instance:

```
{ firstName: Jon
  alias: ['foo', 'fuchs']}
{ firstName: Ann
  alias: ['bar', 'fuchsbar']}
{ firstName: Paul
  alias: ['foobar']}
```

- If I pass in `foob`, I'd like to return Jon.
- If I pass in `foobar`, I'd like to return Jon, Ann, and Paul.
- If I pass in `fuchs`, I'd like to return Jon.

Is it possible to do such a substring query in Mongo?

Comment: It looks like I may be able to solve this with the $where operator - do functions passed to a $where operator take parameters?

Comment: For substring matching you might need the $regex operator.

Comment: @HectorCorrea Actually, it's the reverse. I am *looking* for substrings, not looking for anything that contains `/substring/i` .

Comment: This seems like it will be maximally slow... it will need to hit every document and every array element and do an expensive (relatively speaking) search.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Yeah. That's happening manually (node-side), after selection right now (and it's a huge performance hit). If Mongo doesn't have support for a direct query (which would be faster than post-processing in Node), it may be time to reconsider the schema design.

Comment: I can't think of a way to make it work in MongoDB currently, efficiently, besides a MapReduce, which wouldn't be real time, and still would go through every document....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you index `alias` field and then generate your query the following way for string "fuchs":

```
db.people.find( { "alias" : { "$in" : [ "f","fu","fuc", "fuch", "fuchs" ] } } )
```

You'll need to generate appropriate list of `$in` values yourself, I'm afraid, there is no built in functionality for this in the query language.

Comment: The one problem with this is scalability. For true substring behavior, you'd also need "u", "uc", "uch", "uchs", "c", "ch", "chs", "h", "hs", and "s". And since the query strings are going to be much longer than 5 characters, which ups the number of $in options geometrically.

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize that you meant any substring, based on specific examples I thought you meant starts with substring...  sadly there is nothing better for this (yet).

Comment: No worries! It just means that we need to redesign the schema / query!